# Changing WooCommerce email styles

Tags: php, woocommerce

so... these 2 php scripts:
Header:

```
    <?php
/**
 * Email Header
 *
 * @author  WooThemes
 * @package WooCommerce/Templates/Emails
 * @version 2.4.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="<?php echo is_rtl() ? 'rtl' : 'ltr'?>">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title><?php echo get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ); ?></title>
    </head>
    <body <?php echo is_rtl() ? 'rightmargin' : 'leftmargin'; ?>="0" marginwidth="0" topmargin="0" marginheight="0" offset="0">
        <div id="wrapper" dir="<?php echo is_rtl() ? 'rtl' : 'ltr'?>">
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="100%" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" valign="top">
                        <div id="template_header_image">
                            <?php
                                if ( $img = get_option( 'woocommerce_email_header_image' ) ) {
                                    echo '<p style="margin-top:0;"><img src="' . esc_url( $img ) . '" alt="' . get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) . '" /></p>';
                                }
                            ?>
                        </div>
                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" id="template_container">
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center" valign="top">
                                    <!-- Header -->
                                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" id="template_header">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td id="header_wrapper">
                                                <h1><?php echo $email_heading; ?></h1>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                    <!-- End Header -->
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center" valign="top">
                                    <!-- Body -->
                                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" id="template_body">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td valign="top" id="body_content">
                                                <!-- Content -->
                                                <table border="0" cellpadding="20" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td valign="top">
                                                            <div id="body_content_inner">
```

and content:

```
<?php
/**
 * Admin new order email
 *
 * @author WooThemes
 * @package WooCommerce/Templates/Emails/HTML
 * @version 2.4.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

?>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_email_header', $email_heading ); ?>

<p><?php printf( __( 'You have received an order from %s. The order is as follows:', 'woocommerce' ), $order->get_formatted_billing_full_name() ); ?></p>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table', $order, true, false ); ?>

<h2><a class="link" href="<?php echo admin_url( 'post.php?post=' . $order->id . '&action=edit' ); ?>"><?php printf( __( 'Order #%s', 'woocommerce'), $order->get_order_number() ); ?></a> (<?php printf( '<time datetime="%s">%s</time>', date_i18n( 'c', strtotime( $order->order_date ) ), date_i18n( wc_date_format(), strtotime( $order->order_date ) ) ); ?>)</h2>

<table class="td" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6" style="width: 100%; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;" border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:left;"><?php _e( 'Product', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
            <th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:left;"><?php _e( 'Quantity', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
            <th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:left;"><?php _e( 'Price', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php echo $order->email_order_items_table( false, true ); ?>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <?php
            if ( $totals = $order->get_order_item_totals() ) {
                $i = 0;
                foreach ( $totals as $total ) {
                    $i++;
                    ?><tr>
                        <th class="td" scope="col" colspan="2" style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif; text-align:left; <?php if ( $i == 1 ) echo 'border-top-width: 4px;'; ?>"><?php echo $total['label']; ?></th>
                        <td class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:left; <?php if ( $i == 1 ) echo 'border-top-width: 4px;'; ?>"><?php echo $total['value']; ?></td>
                    </tr><?php
                }
            }
        ?>
    </tfoot>
</table>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_email_after_order_table', $order, true, false ); ?>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_meta', $order, true, false ); ?>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_email_customer_details', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text ); ?>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_email_footer' ); ?>
```

create an email which always goes on to 2 pages. like this:

[image]
[image]

I need to limit the spacing to try to make it fit onto 1 page.

Can anyone advise how it could be tweaked to do this?

Comment: CSS to reduce some padding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the formatting of the emails by [overriding the WooCommerce templates](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/). Essentially you copy the files you wish to override from `/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates` to a directory named "woocommerce" in your theme, for example `/wp-content/themes/YOURTHEME/woocommerce/emails/admin-new-order.php`. You can then change the HTML and CSS as needed to achieve your desired layout.

Another possible option is to use the [WP Better Emails](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-better-emails/) plugin and some mods in your `functions.php`, which I wrote up on my site:

> [Using WP Better Emails with WooCommerce Email Templates](http://justinsilver.com/technology/wordpress/using-wp-better-emails-woocommerce-email-templates/)